# Using SPSS to obtain random samples

Tags: spss

I am not an expert statistician, but am currently the instructor for an introductory statistics course, which uses SPSS 24 in a weekly computer lab tutorial.

In this morning's lab, I distributed a data file to the 20 or so students in the lab.  The data file contained over 50,000 cases; I instructed them to obtain a random sample of 500 cases, then answer various questions about it.  (The idea was that each student would have their own sample to work with.)  To obtain their, sample, I followed the instructions here: http://commfaculty.fullerton.edu/jreinard/bookweb/random.htm

However, it became apparent that several of the students would obtain the same sample of data---which indicates that the samples were not as random as I had hoped.  (I didn't have this problem when I taught the same course previously using Minitab.)  What do I need to tell the students for them to obtain actually random samples?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just going through the GUI, I would instruct the students to PASTE the output into a new syntax window. You can't really diagnose what the issue is with the GUI, as students are unlikely to remember the exact steps they took.

The end code should be something like:

```
SAMPLE 500 FROM 50000.
```

If you want your students to have *exactly* 500 cases.

Now what could potentially happen to have your students select the same samples? One simple one would be if they specified the *from* option to only be 500, e.g. `SAMPLE 500 FROM 500`. This is not a random sample at all, but just selects the *first* 500 cases in the dataset.

If you wanted the students to have the exact same sample, you could set the seed, e.g.:

```
SET SEED 10.
SAMPLE 500 FROM 50000.
```

This shows how to reproduce their results. (So this technically could result in the same samples, but I don't think the seed being the same or students setting it to be the same is a likely explanation.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But what I want to happen is for _each student to have their own sample_ (largely for pedagogical reasons).  Also, my students would likely freak out at the sight of a command-line interface, so I gave them step-by-step instructions for the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by not setting the seed in the random number generator before choosing the sample.  (I had not expected to need to do this, based on my experience with "Random" commands in other software packages.)

In the GUI, choose "Transform" and "Random Number Generators", then "Set Starting Point" and entering some number as a "Fixed value".  A colleague suggested that if each student used their own student ID number, this would give different seeds and different random samples.